# Django FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'custom_field' into field. Choices are:

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django REST 2.2 with rest-auth.

I have a custom user model with an additional field "custom_field". I'm trying to select all users where custom_field="something".

However when I browse to /api/accounts I'll get the following error: *"django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'custom_field' into field. Choices are: auth_token, course, date_joined, email, emailaddress, first_name, groups, id, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, logentry, password, socialaccount, user_permissions, username, userprofile"*

So it seems like my custom_field is not recognized. What did I do wrong?

**user_profile/models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    customField = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

**user_profile/serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(UserDetailsSerializer):

    custom_field = serializers.CharField(source="userprofile.custom_field", allow_blank=True, required=False)

    class Meta(UserDetailsSerializer.Meta):
        fields = UserDetailsSerializer.Meta.fields + ('custom_field')

def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    custom_field = profile_data.get('custom_field')

    instance = super(UserSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)

    # get and update user profile
    profile = instance.userprofile
    if profile_data:
        if custom_field:
            profile.custom_field = custom_field
        profile.save()
    return instance
```

**user_profile/views.py**

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = User.objects.filter(custom_field="something")
        serializer = UserSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**project/urls.py**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('accounts', UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    # This is used for user reset password
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    path('rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
    path('account/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('api/',  include(router.urls)),
```

*rest_auth/serializers.py* (dependency)

```
class UserDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    User model w/o password
    """
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = ('pk', 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
        read_only_fields = ('email', )
```

Comment: How is it look like the `UserDetailsSerializer.Meta` ?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I've added rest_auth/serializers.py to my post.

Comment: Should it be ```User.objects.filter(userprofile__custom_field="something")``` instead of ```User.objects.filter(custom_field="something")``` ? As specified in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/

Comment: The **`custom_field`** filed is defined in **`UserProfile`** model and you are trying to add the same field in a ModelSerializer, which is supposed to serialize the **`User`** model objects. Similar thing in filtering the objects

Comment: As  Lewis mentioned, it should be **`.filter(userprofile__custom_field="something")`**

Comment: @LewisHepburn That works, problem solved. Thank you! I'll have a good read through that.

Comment: @LewisHepburn If you want you can make an answer and I'll approve it.

Comment: Thank you @ArakkalAbu! Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When filtering on a `OnetoOneField`, the associated partner model must be referenced in the query.

```py
User.objects.filter(userprofile__custom_field="something")
```

Notice how `userprofile__` is included in the filter.

More information on on filter lookups can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)